# How to implement SQL Prepare to prevent injection？

Tags: sql, sql-server

I implement SQL connections and statement execution in C # to prevent SQL injection.

My SQL statement is like `SELECT %s FROM %s WHERE %s IN (%s)`. The content after WHERE is not fixed, but it will only contain keywords like AND and OR, and there will be no SELECT.

The Filter clause after my WHERE clause is not fixed, such as column1=1 AND column2=2 or (column2=1 OR column3=2 AND column4=3) etc.
Perhaps it's more complex, is there any good way to implement SQL injection prevention?

Comment: SqlParameters - show your code.

Comment: @DaleK  My SQL statement is like SELECT %s FROM %s WHERE %s IN (%s) The content after WHERE is not fixed,  but it will only contain keywords like AND and OR, and there will be no SELECT.

Comment: Firstly, please add that (and any further relevant information) directly to your question. Secondly that is an anti-pattern right there. SQL is designed to be static, you should be querying a specific table with specific columns. For multiple reasons, including clarity, performance and security.

Comment: You'll have to do it the hard way because you can't parametrize column names, table sources or WHERE conditions. The code above is usually a bad antipattern, it might do some "helper" thing, but it doesn't really help a lot. It's better to use proper queries where only parameters should be provided

Comment: Parameters can only be used for scalar values. In your case you want to change table names and columns. To be safe from injection you'll need to use Dynamic SQL with parameter substitution. For example instead of receiving the "table name" you can receive a numeric code that represents it. Your code can have a Map<> to translate the number to the table name. **Do not receive the table name from the UI**.